# CSS Background on mobile, tablet and other devices that are not PC not working properly

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Hello I have a problem in my website. In the pc version is working perfectly but when you go into a mobile or tablet.

The code I have actually for the Background is this:

```
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/aUiwgHW.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is - could you please provide more information about the actual problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's the mobile version that has the problem? If I compare the screenshot to what I see in your link, the desktop version doesn't get its background image loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in mac! It is a nice website :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this looks fine for me as well. However, if imgur is throwing that error when you load it, you can just move the image to local storage instead. Rather than having your current URL(), just download the image and link to it within your project folder that you have hosted -

i.e `background-image: url(example/*.jpg)`.

This makes it so your background won't be reliant on imgur to load, and instead will just use the file internally.